# genisoimage creates a folder named "." in the ISO

Tags: iso, cd-image

I'm currently trying to generate a CD ISO from a directory with some files in it using the following command: (Yes, I'm using exactly this command to learn how it's done)

```
genisoimage -o test.iso -V helloworld cdiso/
```

For testing, the directory `cdiso` contains two files named `1` and `2`. However, when I generate the ISO using above command, and open the ISO using `file-roller test.iso`, the file list contains - besides the files `1` and `2` - a directory named `.`

How can I forbid `genisoimage` to create this directory inside the ISO image? I already tried adding `-hide "."`, but it didn't work.

Comment: From normal Linux usage I would expect `.` to be the hidden file for "current directory". It might not be possible to remove (Am in doubt though: I would also expect a `..` if that was the case).

Comment: I'm not trying to remove `.` from the creation directory (which is impossible, since it's a representation if the dir itself), but I don't want a folder explicitly named `.` in my ISO.